# What could be causing my dishwasher not to drain?

Tags: dishwasher

The dishwasher stopped draining a few days ago. I reached in to unclog it, but couldn't find a clog. Then I poured some draino in and that didn't do any good either.

I'm thinking maybe the pump or solenoid that controls draining the water is out or jammed? It looks like the drain tube goes up to the sink, so I suppose it uses a pump to drain the water? Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Some pictures:**

I removed the drain cover and used the tube in the picture to siphon all of the water out. The dishwasher is a "[Frigidaire Gallery](https://www.google.com/search?q=frigidaire%20gallery)"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the drain between the dishwasher and your sink? Make sure its not clogged or pinched.  Does the dishwasher sound like its trying to drain?

Comment: Hey Steven. Yeah that was it, I feel dumb :)

Comment: happens to the best of us :)

Comment: @Steven, copy your comment to the answer section and I will up-vote it.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

After ensuring that the drain is clear, the next thing to check is the drain hose that connects your dishwasher to your drain under your sink.  Make sure that hose is not clogged or pinched.